# Extrude and Bevel adobe illustrator problem

Tags: adobe-illustrator

So i'm trying this text effect on adobe illustrator wherein it creates like a hole text appearance.
[image]

The first time I did it, it worked but then the following tries it creates a problem like this.

[image]

I tried again for a few times with the tutorial I saw and it's always like this. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: There is waaaaay more info needed than this to help you. What effect ? How are you doing this ? What tutorial are you following ? Maybe best to just go back through the tutorial again from the beginning. If it worked once, then it is probably some instruction you are not following properly. Otherwise try to explain the steps you are using and *maybe* someone can help.

Comment: If this is using the 3D effect, adjust rotation somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Illustrator's classic 3D effects have always been unreliable. They generate random artifacts like you have seen. The reason can well be somehow tricky path (maybe an error in the font) or a programming bug. As already said in a comment, adjusting a little the view or light sometimes helps. Font error is not plausible here, because a is ok elsewhere. Expand the appearance and copy the well-formed a-hole.

Your example is not 100% 3D effect. The shading is somehow plausible only in letter r. Letter o is partially right, but it has also extra light which does not look right. The rest is a set of manually drawn straight partially transparent stripes. Hopefully the black parallel lines in the next image help to see it:

[image]

The edges of the manually drawn stripes do nor meet the corners of the letters.

The edge lines in the shadings of the holes of letters r and o have a little different directions than the manually drawn stripes. The artist has been in a hurry. As an extra evidence you can compare the original and a succeeded extrusion.

[image]

The text was outlined before extrusion. If you have some rounding effect, expand it, too before the extrusion.